# React passing a component as a param to a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have a function that takes a Component as its' parameter. The function enables users to render their own popups instead of the ones  I provide. However, I'm not able to add some props to said component before adding it to an array.

```
const addCustomSnack = (Snack, position) => {
      let id = generate();

      let snackProps = {
        key: id,
        id,
      };

      Snack.props = {...Snack.props, ...snackProps}
      console.log(Snack);

      buildStyle(position);

      if (messagesNew.length >= 3) {
        que.push(Snack);
        addSnacks(messagesNew);
      } else {
        messagesNew = [...messagesNew, Snack];
        addSnacks(messagesNew);
      }
      console.log(messagesNew);
    };
```

This is what happens

```
Cannot assign to read only property 'props' of object '#<Object>'
```

I have tried the following code

```
const addCustomSnack = (Snack, position) => {
      let id = generate();

      console.log(Snack);

      buildStyle(position);

      if (messagesNew.length >= 3) {
        que.push(Snack);
        addSnacks(messagesNew);
      } else {
        messagesNew = [...messagesNew, <Snack key={id} id={id} />];
        addSnacks(messagesNew);
      }
      console.log(messagesNew);
    };
```

However, it will result in a React.createElement type error.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/sparkling-worker-j5mh2)

Is there any way for me to add those props into the Snack component successfully?

Comment: You are sending a component and the mutating its props like `Snack.props...` Its so wrong on so many levels. Instead, compose props and add `<Snack {...props} />`

Comment: @Rajesh I'm sorry, I should've given more information. If I use the passed Snack and try to add props that way, I get a React.createElement type error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React.cloneElement did exactly what I was looking for. Now, the user can give his own Component, and with cloneElement, I can extend the components props and add it into the array without problems.

```
const addCustomSnack = (Component, position) => {
      let id = generate();


      let props = {
        removeSnack,
        key: id,
        id,
        index: id
      }

      let Snack = React.cloneElement(Component, { ...props }, null);

      buildStyle(position);


      console.log(Snack)
      if (messagesNew.length >= 3) {
        que.push(Snack);
        return addSnacks(messagesNew);
      } else {
        messagesNew = [...messagesNew, Snack];
        return addSnacks(messagesNew);
      }

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what a react [High Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) does: adding props to the component passed as parameter and return a component back.

Comment: Yes, but the function is already in a high order component. Please see the codesandbox link in the post for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting component in Snack then try below way

```
return <Snack {...snackProps} />
```

Using above code this will  render any component that is passed to `addCustomSnack`

Comment: The idea is that it will be added into an array of Snacks, but they need to have certain props added before I add them into the array.  Please see the updated post for details

Answer (score 0):

You could somehow keep an array of the component to render, each with a ref to the component and and its custom properties, then render it with a map, like so:

```
// Snack list
constructor(){
  this.state = { snacks: [] }
}


// ...

const Lollipop = props => (
  <div>
    <h1>Lollipop</h1>
    <span>Taste: </span> {props.taste}
  </div>
)

const ChocolateBar = props => (
  <div>
    <h1>Chocolate bar</h1>
    <span>With fudge: </span> {props.hasFudge ? 'yes': 'no'}
  </div>
)

// Push a custom snack in the list 
const addCustomSnack = (SnackType, props) => this.state.snacks.push({SnackType, props})

// ...
addSnack(Lollipop, {taste: 'cherry'})
addSnack(Lollipop, {taste: 'cola'})
addSnack(ChocolateBar, {hasFudge: true})
addSnack(ChocolateBar, {})

// render the lsit
const SnackList = () => {
  <div>
  { this.state.snacks.map(({SnackType, props}, i) => (
    <SnackType {...props} key={i} />
  ))}
  </div>
}
```